# VBA to replace large Excel Nested IF AND Statement

Tags: vba, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

[image]

I have a large Nested IF AND Statement and I want to avoid using it in vba as is since its unmanageable.

I'll use a simple example:

```
Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(M2>TODAY(),""VALIDATED"",IF(AND(N2="""",M2=""""),""NEW ITEM"",IF(AND(N2=""NEW ITEM"",M2<TODAY()),""NOT VALIDATED"")))
```

What VBA code can I use instead as there are a lot more IF statements to add. Also I want to avoid having to use a loop since there will be 1000's of row.

Update... I have added some new code which works but code goes through each cell and can have an impact on run time of macro. Is there any way to speed this up?

```
Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
For Each Cell In Col
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = 0 Then Cell.Value = "NEW ITEM"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "VALIDATED" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED 1" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) >= Date Then Cell.Value = "VALIDATED"
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Conor

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add I want to apply same logic to all rows in that column from row 2 to last row.

Comment: sorry i've no idea how to upload one

Comment: Basically If col M is greater than today then value in col O = "VALIDATED"

Comment: If you want to add something then edit your question. Also indent code by 4 spaces so it gets displayed as code. Maybe an `If ... Then ... ElseIf ... Else` is an option. Also `Select Case` might be worth looking into. Anyway, if you write it as VBA code first, it might be easier to see where it can be improved.

Comment: If col N is blank and Col M is blank then Col O = "NEW ITEM"

Comment: can there be a case where all rows in Column M will be empty and needs to return all "NEW ITEM" to column O? because in that case it's hard to find the end of the loop, since there can be an infinite number of "New ITEM"

Answer (score 1):

```
this = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Set rNg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("m1:m200")
For Each rCell in rNg.Cells
    If rCell.Value > Weekday(This) Then rCell.Offset(0,2).Value = "Validated"
    If rCell.Value = "" And rCell.Offset(0,1) ="" Then rCell.Offset(0,2).Value = "New Item"
    If rCell.Value < Weekday(This) And rCell.Offset(0,1) ="New Item" Then rCell.Offset(0,2).Value = "Not Validated"
Next rCell
```

Dim your own variables and possibly the ' "" ' cant be refenced with ".value" but either way you didnt try your own code. This is what youre looking for though :P

Comment: what will you do if the entire collection in column M is empty, and it needs to return all "New Item" to Column O ? That's why you are using a constant Range ?

Comment: Well you didnt give me much to go off of and not to mention the only columns you brought up in your posts require that they be blank in some fashion. IF you know the criteria for which you'd stop the loop you can easily adjust what I have suggested with "IF cell so and so = "" then Exit For", correction @ShaiRado the OP didnt give me much to work with. He wasnt descriptive enough and I gave him what he asked for lol

Comment: @Doug: you don't need the `Weekday()` function at all, just compare the value with `this`; I'd call it `now` as it is a time value. Second, OP specified to loop from row 2 to the last filled row in column M, not over a constant range.

Comment: @user1016274 yeah he also doesnt specify what row though. If youre going to harp on me for something like this you might as well be prepared to explain how the hell im supposed to do that with the bare minimum of requirements. Technically no one can really fulfill his request since he isnt capable of giving us exactly what he needs. So there you go :P

Comment: Jesus - Happy Sunday to you too Doug. I'm a beginner and we all have to start from somewhere.

Comment: @Conor I wasnt specifically giving you a hard time, its the other guy who was giving me a hard time about not trying to fulfill a criteria that was never there. Its more like him pointlessly giving me a hard time when it had no grounds to do so, and my making sure that his doing so didnt go unnoticed. If i wanted to specifically call you out for that I would have to begin with (my intent was to help where i could not get flack for nonsense). I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @DougCoats: No need to overreact. Notice that I edited out your typos to support your answer, not to devaluate it. Determining the last used row is so standard that I thought you'd just add one line to help OP out. Re-read the question and you'll see that OP indeed specified the row range.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the code for IF statements however this runs through each cell at a time which can be time consuming. Is there anyway to speed this up?

```
Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
For Each Cell In Col
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = 0 Then Cell.Value = "NEW ITEM"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "VALIDATED" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED 1" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) >= Date Then Cell.Value = "VALIDATED"
Next
```

Comment: If you use `ElseIf` instead of `If`, it will not check every condition for every cell but stop once it has found a match. Also, as it is now, you overwrite `"NEW ITEM"` immediately with `"NOT VALIDATED` in the second `If`. You could also group the cases `=0`, `< Date` and `>= Date` and use nested `If`s or `Select Case` for the sub-cases. Once your code works you can head over to codereview.stackexchange.com to improve it. It probably can be sped up quite a bit using arrays...

Comment: glad you figured out a solution by tinkering, its the best way to learn :)